# Add a pop-up reminder at specific intervals during a presentation in Powerpoint 2013

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

We have these long presentation in our organizations, where is becomes essential to keep track of time and speed of the presentations. We have started various measures such as displaying the the Slide Number and the percentage completion on each slide. Something like:

```
5 of 50 (10%)
```

The above detail is positioned in the page number placeholder via a macro. What I feel is the need to give a reminder at specific intervals to give an idea of how much time has elapsed vis-a-vis how many slides we have completed. What I require is something like this, three times during the presentation. At 25%, 50% and 75%. Powerpoint 2013 already shows the time elapsed in the Presenter view, however the same is not visible to the viewers. Is there any solution. The Reminder would pop-up, stay for 3s and then dis-appear. I will take care of the design etc of the pop-up, just need a way to make it appear at those specific intervals.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal lSleepTime As Long)

Sub OnSlideShowPageChange(ByVal oWindow As SlideShowWindow)
' This will fire with every slide change

    With oWindow.View.Slide

        ' Obviously, this isn't what you want to do, but the two values
        ' will give you the info you need to calculate your 25/50/75% points
        ' and do whatever you need at that point
        MsgBox "This is slide: " & .SlideIndex & " of " & .Parent.Slides.Count

        ' You could instead display a user form that gives the message you want
        ' and include a call to the Sleep API above to have it wait X seconds
        ' then Hide/unload itself

    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Steve, but I am a complete noob when it comes to VBA... Also my kind of solution would be a kind of animation on screen rather than a message box. Could you please extend your help a bit further.

Comment: Sorry.  I sometimes forget that I've switched from StackOverflow (PowerPoint programming stuff) to SuperUser (PowerPoint non-programming stuff).  The message box is simply there as a demo of the routine to trigger a macro with each slide change.  Triggering an animation via vba is somewhere between tricky and impossible and honestly, a bit beyond me.